# textarea saved with break lines cannot be returned as created to the front-end of my project , how to resolve that?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have an html form where I have a textarea box: my process is to create a text in the textarea then click on the save button, after the save the content of the textarea must be shooed in the screen to the client to verify if he want to change anything.. my problem is when I create the textarea with break lignes the text is saved correctly but it cannot be shown on the screen to the client. I found a solution by using :

```
content.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '/
');
```

but the problem is this solution working with google but in Firefox it dosen't work ..

Can anyone help me ??

```html
<textarea id="aide-text-content"></textarea>


($('#aide_content_text textarea').val().length != 0 && $('#aide_content_text textarea').val().length != null)
                {
                    content = $('#aide_content_text textarea').val();
                    content = content.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '                                                                                                \
```

Comment: If you're going to show it in HTML, you should convert the line break characters to `<br />` tags.

Comment: i tryed that but unfortunatelyit dosn't work

Comment: Show us your code. It's impossible to tell what you're trying to do without any semblance of code in your question.

Comment: if you wrap the string in a <pre> tag, it should break lines nicely.

Comment: i edit the pub and add it the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `white-space: pre` or `white-space: pre-wrap` to break newlines:

```js
const myText = 'Hello World!\n\nLet\'s get some\nLINEBREAKS\nin here';
document.getElementById('container').textContent = myText;
```

```css
#container {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```